# Animate a circle whose radius and evolution times are provided as arrays

Tags: python, animation

How do I animate a circle when I have its radius as a function of time (I have them both as arrays) in Python? That is, I want the frames to follow the times given in the time array.

I did the following which works but does not make use of FuncAnimation() (which is a problem as I need to save it as a GIF or mp4).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

time = np.array([0.0,0.1,0.122,0.124,0.4,0.45,0.5,1.2,1.4,1.5])
r = np.array([100.0,99.0,90.0,80.0,78.0,50.0,40.0,30.0,10.0,5.0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-max(r),max(r))
ax.set_ylim(-max(r),max(r))

for j in range(len(time)):

    ax.add_artist(plt.Circle((0, 0), r[j], color='r'))
    ax.set_title(str(time[j]))
    fig.canvas.draw()
    if j+1==len(time):
        break
    plt.pause((time[j+1]-time[j]))
    plt.gca().cla()

plt.show()
```

Is there a way to do it using FuncAnimation() and save it?

Comment: you can generate every frame as separated gif and later convert to animated GIF or mp4 with programs like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or imagemagick. They also may have modules in Python like [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy)

Comment: as I know `FuncAnimation()` can't change times between frames but maybe if you use frametime = 0.02 then all values in list `time` you could represent as a multiple of 0.02 - this way you can display some elements only in one frame, other in many frames.

Comment: This is a dummy code. My actual code has a few thousand entries in the time and r arrays. I'll try your way of making an animation file from separated gifs.